# Pivot Tables - VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, olap-cube

I want to select some values through VBA in Pivot Table which is linked to OLAP Cube.
As I know such modification can be realised by typing:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("[parameter].[parameter]").VisibleItemsList = Array("value1","value2","value3")
```

Since get list of parameters from cells in Excel sheet, I wrote simple function which - In mentioned example - returns:

```
""value1","value2","value3""
```

I can't use such string as parameter for Array function (as it recognize it as one string), so I've tried to convert it to Array of Variant, typing above code:

```
Dim tableVar() As Variant

 myVar = Replace(myVar, Chr(34), "") 
 myVar = Split(myVar, ",") 
 lowerB =LBound(myVar) 
 upperB = UBound(myVar)

 ReDim tablica(lowerB To upperB)
  For i = lowerB To upperB 
     tableVar(i) = myVar(i) 
  Next i
```

Unfortunately it changes nothing - when I'm calling:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("[parameter].[parameter]").VisibleItemsList = tableVar
```

I'm still receiving an error message.
Could you help me, please?

Comment: What is the exact error you're getting?

Comment: Thank you for advice - since Stackoverflow have so many users it's not so simple to response fast. My error is: Run-time error '1004':
The item could not be found in the OLAP Cube

Comment: Why not just have your function return a pipe (|)-delimited list of fields, then you can just use `Split(myVar, "|")` to create the array.

Answer (score 1):

you have a typo in your code, `daty` should say `myVar`.
(Either that or we're missing more details)

Comment: Yes, you're right - thanks - before asking question, I rewrote part of my code. Anyway - it doesn't resolve my problem.

Comment: it seems that I made another mystake - I forgot to change "tablica" to "tableVar"

Answer (score 0):

Stupid thing, but error message is simply correct - there's no such items in Cube:

> Run-time error '1004': The item could not be found in the OLAP Cube

I gave incorrect parameter here:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("[parameter].[parameter]").VisibleItemsList = tableVar
```

My code was unnecessary complicated - sorry for wasting your time.
Now my problem will be - how to check if specific dimensions or whole Cube exist...
Thanks once more for help.